# Ember-cli ember serve AssertionError (false == true)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to follow the "Getting Started" section at ember-cli.com, but I'm getting an error when attempting to "ember serve":

```
version: 0.1.6
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200/
File: project/app.js
false == true
AssertionError: false == true
    at Visitor.PVp.visitWithoutReset (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/esnext/node_modules/recast/node_modules/ast-types/lib/path-visitor.js:135:12)
    at Visitor.PVp.visit (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/esnext/node_modules/recast/node_modules/ast-types/lib/path-visitor.js:117:21)
    at Function.transform (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/esnext/node_modules/regenerator/lib/visit.js:31:18)
    at transform (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/esnext/lib/index.js:86:23)
    at compile (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/esnext/lib/index.js:33:9)
    at EsnextFilter.processString (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/index.js:41:16)
    at EsnextFilter.Filter.processFile (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-filter/index.js:136:31)
    at Promise.resolve.then.catch.err.file (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-filter/index.js:82:21)
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-filter/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:490:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/tiagomatos/Desktop/project/node_modules/ember-cli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-esnext/node_modules/broccoli-filter/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:502:17)
```

I can't seem to find anyone else with the same issue, so I'm kind of lost. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Extra context:

OS: OS X Yosemite

```
$ node -v
v0.10.35
$ npm -v
2.1.18
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be fixed by replacing `"ember-cli-esnext": "0.1.1"` with `"ember-cli-6to5": "0.2.1"` in your `package.json` file and then run `npm install`.

Alternatively, you can also upgrade to ember-cli 0.1.7 following [these upgrade instructions](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.7).

More [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2968) and [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/0cca8004acdc780e774e6e89e652513e1acd78ab).

Comment: Yes, I just found out that at the emberjs discussion forum. Thank you. I'm going to accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow let's me :)

Comment: I just want to note for others that upgrading to 0.1.7 does this exact same change, so you're not doing anything all that weird by making it yourself.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.  When I initially posted this answer 0.1.7 hadn't been released.